# MOxy @XmlReadOnly annotation

Tags: jaxb, jersey, moxy, jersey-1.0

I'm using Jersey 1.18 on Glassfish 3.1.2, and I'm trying to make an attribute read-only. I already using MOxy @XmlReadOnly, but it gets marshaled.

```
@XmlReadOnly
private String password;
```

There's anything that can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding also `@XmlElement`, as stated by the [documentation of `@XmlReadonly`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/annotations/XmlReadOnly.html) solved the problem for me:

```
@XmlElement
@XmlReadOnly
private String password;
```